# VS 2010 web.config transformation displaying incorrectly in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The problem can be better explained with this image.

[image]

As you can see, the transformed files are displaying as part of web.config and also as individual files. But they are the same if I open them or delete them. If I delete and undo it using TFS, that restores as part of web.config. After another check-in that again it shows up as individual.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: how did you add these entries? can you please (re)clarify what happens when you `Remove` the files that are NOT under the `Web.config` file? (do not delete them off disk simply remove the ones not under web.config from the solution explorer) -  I would expect that to fix it; can you detail how they come back (After which action)

Comment: @wal I did not delete them from disk. There is only one copy of each in the disk. I did delete them from the solution. The ones under web.config also get deleted and I restore them by undoing the changes in TFS. That temporarily fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this by deleting them and then pressing right click to web.config -> Add Config Transform.